# Java Map with Set as Value. How to get all values for a given key?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, set, key-value

I need your help. I have this method:

```java
Set<Games> getGames(Player player) {
    Map<User, Set<Games>> map = repository.getGamesMap();
    Set<Games> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Player, Set<Games>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(player)) {
            Set<Games> games = entry.getValue();
            result.addAll(games);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The outcome is that nothing is added to result Set. If I skip the if condition, everything is added (games of all players, not only of a given one).

If I try something like:

```java
return newHashSet(repository.getGamesMap().get(user));
```

I get null pointer when testing, even though games are added. So I probably have to check the key for each entry and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: how do you expect the `.equals()` to work for two player instances? perhaps this is the key to your problem. Try to override the default `equals()` method inside the Player class and see what happens. Alternatively, try to change the if statement to check the fields of the player class that you are interested in, when checking for player equality.

Comment: If `equals()` correctly compare the `player` parameter and a `Player` key in the map as being equal, but `get(user)` doesn't work, then you're likely using a `HashMap` but didn't correctly implement the `hashCode()` in the `Player` class. But, since we can't see the `Player` class, that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably in the if statement, as you correctly pointed out. 
It seems that you have not overridden `.equals()` method inside the Player class. 
If you don't want to do that, you can change the if statement to something like:

```
if (entry.getKey().getName().equals(player.getName())) {
```

assuming that the Player class has a method getName() returning a String and that you want to compare two Player instances based on this string equality. 
You can adapt this equality condition either inside the if statement (as above), or inside the .equals() method of the Player (also overriding the hashCode() method, as Andreas commented).

If you did override the `equals()` method, but it still doesn't work, try to debug this method or just print when it returns true and when false.

Comment: That was it. Wow